# Missing argument in a function

Tags: r

I have an ODE function LVM() which takes the arguments time,population, carry capacity and growth rate. I need to compute its stability by finding the Jacobian using 'pracma' R package or 'rootSolve' package but i get an error

> Error in fun(x, ...) : argument "r" is missing, with no default

my function is;

```
LVM <- function(t,pop,int_mat,str_mat,carry_cap,r){ 
dN=r*pop*((carry_cap-(int_mat*str_mat)%*%pop)/carry_cap)
  return(dN)
}
```

When i compute the Jacobian as below;

```
jacobian(LVM,c(0.287778,0.2553485,0.147619,0.3661074,0.4390739,0.1270218,0.4533318,0.2236241,0.3555208,0.2102366))
```

where  the numerical values are population densities i get an error

> Error in fun(x, ...) : argument "r" is missing, with no default

Your input will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a modified function `LVM_V2` which takes a vector of parameters instead
    of 6 parameters, I get the following output. Is this the expected output

Mapping of parameters:

```
#r=>x[6]
#pop => x[2]
#carry_cap => x[5]
#int_mat => x[3]
#str_mat => x[4]


LVM_V2 <- function(x){ 
 dN=x[6]*x[2]*((x[5]-(x[3]*x[4])%*%x[2])/x[5])
 return(dN)
}

pracma::jacobian(LVM_V2,c(0.287778,0.2553485,0.147619,0.3661074,0.4390739,0.1270218,0.4533318,0.2236241,0.3555208,0.2102366))

#     [,1]      [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        [,5]      [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    0 0.1190372 -0.006905828 -0.002784515 0.002321776 0.2473229    0    0    0     0
```

Note that the parameter `t` remains unused in your function